# typeerror 'int' object is not iterable

Tags: python-3.x

I am using the function below to compute inverse term frequencies. I am trying to call function. total_all is a list

```
 inverse_document_frequencies(total_all)

   def inverse_document_frequencies(tokenized_documents):
   idf_values = {}
   global dfInv
   dfInv = pd.DataFrame() 
   tokenized_documents = [tokenize(d) for d in words]
   all_tokens_set = set([item for sublist in tokenized_documents for item in 
sublist])
   for tkn in all_tokens_set:
   contains_token = len(list(map(lambda doc: tkn in doc, tokenized_documents)))
    idf_values[tkn] = 1 + math.log(len(tokenized_documents)/(sum(contains_token))) 
dfInv=pd.DataFrame(data ={'tkn':contains_token,'idf_values':idf_values[tkn]})
return dfInv
```

I have added parantheses and changed indentation, and this helps get rid of the syntax error. I am getting an error below on calling the function.
typeerror 'int' object is not iterable.

Comment: Missing `)` on the previous line, `3` opens only `2` closes. And indentation is important.

Comment: I have made the changes. I am still getting a syntax  error for the second last line of code.

Answer (score 1):

No Syntax error in following code. It was all about indentation and missing parenthesis

```
def inverse_document_frequencies(tokenized_documents):
    idf_values = {}
    global dfInv
    dfInv = pd.DataFrame() 
    tokenized_documents = [tokenize(d) for d in words]
    all_tokens_set = set([item for sublist in tokenized_documents for item in 
sublist])
    for tkn in all_tokens_set:
        contains_token = len(list(map(lambda doc: tkn in doc, tokenized_documents)))
        idf_values[tkn] = 1 + math.log(len(tokenized_documents)/(sum(contains_token)))
        dfInv=pd.DataFrame({'tkn':contains_token,'idf_values':idf_values[tkn]})
    return dfInv
```

Comment: thanks @saurabh, it works now. I am trying to call function.   
    inverse_document_frequencies(total_all).                  I am getting an error message : typeerror 'int'object is not iterable. Total_all is list object

Comment: Please share the stacktrace